# How to set a regular lattice of turtles in the world

Tags: netlogo

I would like to set a regular grid of turtles. With the following example, I have gotten to distribute the reader agents equally spaced in the x dimension, but I can not set a maximum number of agents per row and place the followings rows of readers in the world.

```
breed [readers reader]

globals [ reader-ycor  ]

to setup
  clear-all
  setup-globals
  setup-readers
end

to setup-globals
  set-default-shape readers "square 2" 
  set reader-ycor (min-pycor + 1)
end

to setup-readers
  let horizontal-interval (world-width / number-of-readers)
  create-readers number-of-readers [
    set color green
    setxy (min-pxcor - 0.5 + horizontal-interval * (0.5 + who)) reader-ycor 
    set size 3
    set label ""
  ]
end

to go
  setup
end
```

The global `number-of-readers` indicates the total number of `readers`, and  `max-number-per-row` would be a variable set to 10 (the maximum number of readers per row).

I do not know how to tell the x-coordinate to stop when a row has 10 readers and how to tell Netlogo to add a new row of readers when the `who` of a reader is greater than 10.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think instead of using `who` numbers (which is not recommended) you might be better off just calculating the coordinates manually and then spawning the turtles on the calculated values. With this setup:

```
breed [ readers reader ]

to setup
  ca
  spawn-by-row
  reset-ticks
end
```

And these sliders for readers per row and number of readers:

[image]

This code will build readers from the lowest x/y value (details in comments):

```
to spawn-by-row
  ; get the intervals
  let h-int world-width / readers-per-row 
  let v-int world-height / readers-per-row

  ; Get a range of horizontal and vertical coordinates, starting at half
  ; of the interval value from the minimum x coordinate
  let h-vals ( range ( min-pxcor + h-int / 2 ) max-pxcor h-int )
  let v-vals ( range ( min-pycor + v-int / 2 ) max-pycor v-int )

  ; Create an empty list to build into
  let possible-coords []

  ; For each possible vertical value, map all horizontal values in order and
  ; combine these into an ordered list starting at the lowest px and py coords

  foreach v-vals [
    v -> 
    set possible-coords ( sentence possible-coords map [ i -> (list i v) ] h-vals )
  ]

  ; Use the number of readers to sublist the possible coordinates, and
  ; create a turtle at each of the coordinate combinations left.
  let use-coords sublist possible-coords 0 number-of-readers
  foreach use-coords [
    coords ->
    create-readers 1 [
      setxy item 0 coords item 1 coords
      set shape "square 2"
    ]
  ]
end
```

[image]

If you have more `number-of-readers` than can be accommodated by `readers-per-row` you will throw an error, but that would be easily fixed.

**Edit 2:**

Add a slider for `distance-var` to the interface above, and try this modified version of `spawn-by-row`

```
to spawn-by-row

  ; Get a range of coordinate values
  let half-step 0.5 * distance-var
  let d-vals ( range ( min-pxcor + half-step ) ( max-pxcor ) distance-var )

  ; Create an empty list to build into
  let possible-coords []

  ; For each possible vertical value, map all horizontal values in order and
  ; combine these into an ordered list starting at the lowest px and py coords

  foreach d-vals [
    d ->
    set possible-coords ( sentence possible-coords map [ i -> (list i d) ] d-vals )
  ]

  ; Use the number of readers to sublist the possible coordinates, and
  ; create a turtle at each of the coordinate combinations left.
  let max-positions length possible-coords
  if max-positions > number-of-readers [ set max-positions number-of-readers ]
  let use-coords sublist possible-coords 0 max-positions
  foreach use-coords [
    coords ->
    create-readers 1 [
      setxy item 0 coords item 1 coords
      set shape "dot"
      set color white
    ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: I would like to control the separation distance between readers, all the same distance but variable an input parameter. May you indicate me how to make this change?. Thank you.

Comment: @pablo - Can you explain more what you mean with the error? Did you copy the example code into a blank model to try it out? Also, the separation distance between readers is determined by (as in your question) the number of readers per row, if I understand you correctly. I will make some clarifying edits in my answer.

Comment: Thank you. The code of your solution works perfectly. I would like to add to the code the possibility of setting the distance between readers. What variable should I change or add to your code to fix a separation distance?

Comment: @pablo - Can you explain a little more what you mean? As it is, the separation between readers is defined by the width of the world and the number of readers in a given row / column. If you impose a distance between readers value, you will be contradicting that `readers-per-row` value. Are you trying to say that instead of basing reader position on the world width (eg `readers-per-row`) you want the user to be able to input a "distance between readers" value?

Comment: Yes, that is what I intended to do. Sorry if I have not explained well the problem. Now, readers separation is based on the world dimensions but, if possible, I would need to set the distance between readers. The world has fixed dimensions, thus it is a problem to give a number of readers per row or per column that not overpass the limits of the world for a given separation distance.

Comment: @pablo - Have a look at my edits, see if that's closer to what you're after!

Comment: Yes. It is exactly the solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed a solution but using the avoidable `who` numbers.

```
breed [readers reader]
undirected-link-breed [ rris rri ]

globals [ reader-ycor  ]

to setup
  clear-all
  ask patches [ set pcolor blue - 3 ]
  setup-globals
  setup-readers
end

to setup-globals
  set-default-shape readers "square 2"
  set separation-distance-ratio 10 ; should be > 10
  set number-of-readers 24
  set interf-rri-radius 110
end

to setup-readers
  let horizontal-interval (world-width / separation-distance-ratio )
  let vertical-interval (world-height / separation-distance-ratio ) 
  create-readers number-of-readers [
    setxy (min-pxcor - 0.5 + horizontal-interval * (0.5 + who mod 10 )) 
             (min-pycor - 0.5 + vertical-interval * (0.5 + floor (who / 10) ) ) 
    set size 2.5
    set color green
  ]
  ask readers [ create-rris-with other readers in-radius interf-rri-radius ]
end

to go
  setup
end
```